# How to get unique key values from List of maps in Scala

Tags: json, scala, dictionary

There are duplicated maps in a list where I need to get unique maps.
Instead of 2 maps getting 4 maps.

Input:

```scala
List(
    Map(LN->ABC,FN->CDE, Phones -> List(Map(CellPhone-> 1388798,sqno ->1))),
    Map(LN->ABC,FN->CDE, Phones -> List(Map(CellPhone-> 1388798,sqno ->1))),
    Map(LN->DNB,FN->CDE, Phones -> List(Map(CellPhone-> 1388780,sqno ->2))),
    Map(LN->DNB,FN->CDE, Phones -> List(Map(CellPhone-> 1388780,sqno ->2)))
)
```

Required Output:

```scala
Map(LN->ABC,FN->CDE, Phones -> List(Map(CellPhone-> 1388798,sqno ->1))),
Map(LN->DNB,FN->CDE, Phones -> List(Map(CellPhone-> 1388780,sqno ->1))))
```

I have tried as below :

```scala
val t= tmp.map(_.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Any]]])
val map = temp match {
  case Some(x) => x.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Any]) { (map,entry) =>  entry) }
  case None => throw new Exception("Error")
}
```

and getting values as:

```scala
Map(LN->DNB,FN->CDE, Phones -> List(Map(CellPhone-> 1388798,sqno ->1))
```

instead of :

```scala
Map(LN->ABC,FN->CDE, Phones -> List(Map(CellPhone-> 1388798,sqno ->1))),
Map(LN->DNB,FN->CDE, Phones -> List(Map(CellPhone-> 1388780,sqno ->1))))
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: How about `input.distinct`?

Comment: Input is of type List[Map[String,Any]] and distinct gives same output without change

Comment: no, it [doesn't](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/nHjdniA7RciV1cZliC8kcw)

Comment: That data format sounds awfully like a JSON, if that is the case I would recommend using a proper library and data type.

Comment: Yes @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  .  It is a Json which is parsed using Jackson parser as Map[String,Any]. And the generated map has nested structure where duplicates need to be removed in one of the key where the values are List[Maps[String,Any] .

Comment: If you are in **Scala** I would recommend using a **Scala** library that allows you to parse that to either a proper case class or to a properly typed `Json` data type rather than `Map[String, Any]`

Comment: Could you please suggest a good library as I tried few and did not work for my use case to remove duplicates. Also it is 2.11 and many frameworks support >2.11.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use scala's inbuild **distinct** fun which internally uses HashSet and iterate through the whole given collection and adds elements to that HashSet which don't accept duplicate data.

```
object HelloWorld {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
         var q = List(
      Map("LN"->"ABC","FN"->"CDE", "Phones" -> List(Map("CellPhone"-> "1388798", "sqno" -> "1"))),
      Map("LN"->"ABC","FN"->"CDE", "Phones" -> List(Map("CellPhone"-> "1388798","sqno" ->"1"))),
      Map("LN"->"DNB","FN"->"CDE", "Phones" -> List(Map("CellPhone"-> "1388780","sqno" ->"2"))),
      Map("LN"->"DNB","FN"->"CDE", "Phones" -> List(Map("CellPhone"-> "1388780","sqno" ->"2")))
    )
    
    println(q.distinct)
   }
}
```

**RESP**:  List(Map(LN -> ABC, FN -> CDE, Phones -> List(Map(CellPhone -> 1388798, sqno -> 1))), Map(LN -> DNB, FN -> CDE, Phones -> List(Map(CellPhone -> 1388780, sqno -> 2))))